# I could not use my username and password in my created database SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2015, database-connection

This is just a simple login data using SQL Server database. I'm having trouble using my pre-defined username and password in the database.

I checked my connection string and I always get this error. This is the error I'm getting whenever I input the details in the text box:

[image: ERROR]

and here is the table data:

[image: click for table data]

Comment: looks like your problem is with the string connection. can you post it removing any sensitive information?

Comment: SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=DESKTOP-CVKHQEV\AMIEL;Initial Catalog=Syslog;Integrated Security=True,");

Comment: Try removing the comma behind `Integrated Security=True,` it should be `Integrated Security=True;` with a semicolon.

Comment: yeah i realized this moments after i tried manipulating the connection string thanks!